# Running Jive Dev Enrivonment on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: java, maven, windows-7-x64, jive

I've followed the following instructions to get Jive up and running on a windows 7 64 bit machine.

Java

1. Install latest version of Java
2. Download Java SE 6 Update 37 JDK (includes JRE) but do not install yet
3. Open a new command prompt and run java --version to verify that it is correctly installed.
4. If you receive an error saying version 1.5 was expected and 1.7 was found, make sure all versions of software are for the correct OS (64 or 32 bit) which may require you to uninstall current versions (system will use the most recent version installed, even if you try to install an older version after the newer version was installed)

Eclipse

1. Download & install Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers
2. Once installed, create your default workspace and access Help – Eclipse Marketplace
3. Search the marketplace for SubClipse and install
4. Search the marketplace for Maven Integration for Eclipse WTP and install

PostGres

1. Install postgreSQL
2. Once you have installed postgres, uninstall java from the C:\oracle\Ora11gR2\product\11.2.0\client_1 directory and install Java version 7 there.
3. Open pgAdmin, click on the “plug” to create a new connection
4. Set name and host to localhost and include your network usename, port number, and password used when installing postgres
5. Expand the database tree, right click to add new login role - configure new login role as super user by selecting all options under role privileges, set PW under definition tab, and hit ok
6. exit or disconnect and log back in as your user
7. Create desired databases

Maven

1. Install binary mirror download of maven
2. Unzip the distribution archive, i.e. apache-maven-3.0.4-bin.zip to the directory you wish to install Maven 3.0.4. These instructions assume you chose C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation. The subdirectory apache-maven-3.0.4 will be created from the archive.
3. Unzip the distribution archive, i.e. apache-maven-3.0.4-bin.zip to the directory you wish to install Maven 3.0.4. These instructions assume you chose C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation. The subdirectory apache-maven-3.0.4 will be created from the archive.
4. Go to your environment variable (How to) dialog within Control Panel\System and Security\System and access Advanced system settings. On the System properties dialog, go to the Advanced tab and click “Environment Variables”
5. Add the M2_HOME variable in the system variables with the value C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.0.4
6. add the M2 environment variable in the system variables with the value %M2_HOME%\bin
7. add the MAVEN_OPTS environment variable in the user variables to specify JVM properties, e.g. the value -Xms256m -Xmx512m
8. update/create the Path environment variable in the system variables and append the value %M2% to add Maven available in the command line. (add ;%M2% to the end of the path value)
9. Add/Update JAVA_HOME in your system variables and set the value to the location of your JDK, e.g. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_02
10. Make sure that %JAVA_HOME%\bin is in your Path environment variable.  If not, append to existing Path system variable (remember to separate by semi-colon)
11. Open a new command prompt and run mvn --version to verify that it is correctly installed.
12. If this fails investigate the issues discussed in this article.

In the user’s directory (ie \USERNAME.m2) there will be a .m2 directory for the Maven repository.  Create a settings.xml file in that directory with the repository settings

Jive Build

1. Check Jive out of SVN repository
2. edit the pom.xml file in the project root. Make sure the jive short version at about line 20 is set correctly: 5.0.2.1
3. Open a terminal window. Change to the top level project directory
4. Run this:  mvn clean install -Djive.setup=false -P external

This is where i get stuck - I get a cmd prompt error when i run mvn clean install -Djive.setup=false -X external to get the debug log, and it says it's still missing the repository.

I've seen some documentation saying to get this all working on a windows 7 machien you should use a VM, but i've also seen that it's possible to do, just not supported.

Has anybody successfully installed, built, and ran jive on windows 7?

Answer (score 2):

Following https://community.jivesoftware.com/docs/DOC-3547 for setting up maven says:

Note: this Maven configuration provides access to Jive binaries and sources via the maven-secure.jivesoftware.com server; it requires login access.  See the bottom of the document where to put your login information.

Please request maven access by creating a Supportal case.  If you do not have a company group, you may email your maven request to accountsupport@jivesoftware.com

It's possible that you don't have the required access.

Answer (score 0):

the tricky part is getting the eae engine up and running in windows 7.  It works from Jive 6 onwards.  I remember in Jive 5 running the eae engine in a linux vm and hooking into it.  after the setup, unless your doing development that requries the eae engine then you can just shut it off...