# coding, data migration and deployment process using jive

Tags: jive

I am new to Jive, currently going through the documentation provided on https://docs.jivesoftware.com/.
what I am looking for is

1. Any specific editor to write code in jive x
2. How to migrate data into jive
3. Deployment process followed by jive. Like where to develop, test, deploy.

So anyone who has worked using jive, can provide some links/tips.

Comment: There are 3 flavors of Jive-x, it may be helpful to specify which one applies to you.  There is Cloud (hosted by Jive, limited customizations), Hosted (hosted by Jive, highly customizable), and On-Prem (same as hosted, but you are doing the hosting).

Also, it may be helpful to specify what type(s) of customizations you are using, and what OS you are running.  I am on a Mac... I use Sublime for coding add-ons and writing REST scripts, and I use Eclipse for anything Java related (plugins and productized command line tools).

Comment: @RobertHanson Thanks for the info. Will let you know shortly about the jive-x  flavor we will be using with OS & other editors.

Comment: @RobertHanson I got some preliminary info like, we will be developing using Eclipse IDE on Windows PC with Maven <M2Eclipse> plugins. Referred this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145575/running-jive-dev-enrivonment-on-windows-7-64-bit?rq=1. Is it good option?

Comment: @RobertHanson we are using on-prem flavor. Not sure how to connect jivex with Eclipse though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There is no specific editor to write code for Jive. This is a personal preference which might also depend if you are writing a Plugin in Java or an Add-On in JS. I prefer to use IntelliJ in general.
2. The best option to migrate data into Jive is to use the REST API. It is important to rate-limit the requests to not overload the instance but the API should be able to handle a considerable number of requests, depending on the underlying infrastructure. You could in theory also use the DB to migrate data into Jive but that would require a deep knowledge of the Jive architecture and the chances of breaking something are high.
3. For development and early testing the best is a local instance, which you can setup following these [steps](https://community.jivesoftware.com/docs/DOC-111844). For full end-to-end testing the best is to have a UAT environment which replicates as much as possible the production instance/infrastructure.

Comment: Barbosa Thanks for valuable inputs. I am looking into jivex which is recently acquired by Lithium. Further I got 2 links https://sandbox.jiveon.com/ & https://community.lithium.com/t5/Developer-Documentation/bd-p/dev-doc-portal not sure which doc/tutorial to follow. Any idea on it?

Comment: @JeevanBodas, the acquisition is very new the Jive documentation hasn't been migrated over to Lithium's site (and perhaps may never move)/  The site sandbox.jiveon.com is a site that can be used for developers for testing.  Never put private data on this server, because potentially all Jive developers would be able to access it.  However this is a good place to try out an add-on with fake data.

Comment: For migrations to a Jive-x Cloud instance, REST is your only option.  And even on hosted, REST is still probably the best option.  I've been doing migrations to Jive for two years and generally you can use REST to recreate Places, People, and Content with the following exceptions.  You can't back-date Ideas, but you can with everything else.  If you use the run-as API (https://community.jivesoftware.com/docs/DOC-110343) you can repost content as the original author.  You will have issues importing embedded video, but importing mp4's as Video content will work.

Comment: The link provided is for Plugin development.  This is only possible on Hosted and On-Prem instances.  It isn't possible on Cloud.  You may be better off starting here, https://developer.jivesoftware.com.  Also, don't hesitate to ask development questions in JiveWorks (http://community.jivesoftware.com/), it is still very appropriate to ask Jive-x developer questions there, regardless of the acquisition by Lithium.

Comment: @RobertHanson Thanks for the info. It will surely help me to start my journey with jive.

Comment: @RobertHanson the link I have posted is not exclusive for plugin development but also for creating a local dev instance of Jive, which was part of the question. You are correct, REST is the only option for Cloud instances and custom plugins are also not allowed on those instances.

Comment: @AndréBarbosa "the link I have posted is not exclusive for plugin development" ... oh yes, yes, right. Additional info - It requires getting access to Jive's maven repo, which can be requested via a Jive support case or talking to your sales rep.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. It's one of the steps mentioned on that link.

Comment: @AndréBarbosa Can you please let us know how we can get instance of jivex for experimentation or say learning purpose

Comment: If you are an existing customer you would need to request a preview instance (this was the process at least in the Jive days). If you are just exploring the possibility of becoming a customer you might be able to request a demo instance and do your tests there.